# Progress Bar width to change when increment button clicked. Javascript

Tags: javascript

*Working now*

Ok so hello, im looking for help with the code below:

When i click the increment button the values increment by one on each click, which is essentially what i want it do to. But I also want the blue progress bar to fill the bar as the numbers increase.
I have a run able piece of code which may help with de-bugging here below.
 All help appreciated as i am new to this site Thanks.

```js
function getProgress() {
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style","width");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;
 }

function setProgress(value) {
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow",value);
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style","width: " +value+ "%"); 
 document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value+ "%"); 
}

function increment() {
 var i = getProgress();
 if(i < 100){
  i++;
  setProgress(i); 
 }else{
  alert("Progress Complete!");
 }
}

function decrement() {
 var d = getProgress();
 setProgress(d - 1);
}

function resetButton() {
 var r = getProgress();
 setProgress(r = 0);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
 
  </head>
  <body>
 <!-- Container -->
 <div class="container">
 
    <h1>This Process bar is animated using <br>JavaScript!</h1>
 <br>
 
 <!-- Div For Progress Bar -->
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"  style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progressbar" >0%</div>
 </div>
 
 <br>
 <!-- Buttons -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "increment()">Increment</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="resetButton()">Reset</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="">Start Auto Progress!</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="">Stop Auto Progress!</button>
 
 <p id="value"> </p>
 <!-- End of Container -->
 </div>
 
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only missing a single colon in your line to set width.  Should be `"width: " + value` instead.

Comment: No problem and good luck with the work!  Welcome to Stack Overflow!